# RenderBody() method in an if statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, layout

I've got a project with a lot of views that have the same layout, so I used _ViewStart to make them all have the same layout. In that layout, I use @RenderBody() to fill the layout in with the content of a page. That works.

Now I'm trying to put @RenderBody() in an if statement. In the else statement I have put some html. It looks like this:

```
    ...*/
    @if (condition == true) { 
        @RenderBody()
    } else {
        <p>Some text if the condition is false</p>
    }
    /*...
```

When I run this code and the condition is false, I get this error:

> System.Web.HttpException: The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page "~/Views/Shared/_BasicLayout.cshtml".

So my question is:

How do I put @RenderBody() in an if statement?

On request, here is the whole _BasicLayout body:

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li @(@ViewBag.Title == "Films" ? "class=active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Films", "List", "FilmSelectie")</li>
                <li @(@ViewBag.Title == "Index" ? "class=active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Voorstellingen", "Index", "Voorstelling")</li>
                <li @(@ViewBag.Title == "Nieuwsbrief" ? "class=active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Nieuwsbrief", "Nieuwsbrief", "Nieuwsbrief")</li>
                <li @(@ViewBag.Title == "Contact" ? "class=active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "ContactBreda", "Contact")</li>
                <li @(@ViewBag.Title == "Login" ? "class=active" : "")>@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "User")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="row panel" style="display:block; box-shadow: none;margin-top:5px;margin:0;margin-left:0px;">
    <div id="film informatie" class="col-xs-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8" style="display:block; box-shadow:none; margin-top:20px;">
        @if (0 == 1) { 
            @RenderBody()
        } else {
            <h2>Geen toegang!</h2>
            <p>U heeft geen toegang tot deze pagina. Log in met een geschikt account om op deze pagina te komen.</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="panel-footer" style="display:block; text-align:center;">
        <p>
            © 2015 Cinema Jam || Chasséveld 1, Breda ||
            <a  href="https://www.facebook.com/CinemaJamBreda" target="_blank"><img style="width:20px; height:20px;" src="~/Content/facebook.png" alt="CinemaJam FacebookPagina"></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/CinemaJamB3" target="_blank"><img style="width:20px; height:20px;"  src="~/Content/twitter.png" alt="CinemaJam TwitterPagina"></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

(somehow i can not paste the header and the start of the body in stack overflow, it contains references to bootstrap)

Comment: What condition are you wanting to check, and why? Seems like you're trying to put logic in your layout that instead belongs on your views.

Comment: Can you show us what your `_BasicLayout.cshtml` looks like? Created a test project and I can simply remove `@RenderBody()` from `_Layout.cshtml` without problems.

Comment: I'm trying to add a check on each page, which checks wether a user may have acces to it or not.

Comment: @Janneman96 what version of MVC are you using? Do you have good reasons for not using [`[Authorize]`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF)?

Comment: @DionV. I've edited the post, now it contains the full code.

Comment: @DionV. I don't know [Authorize], I'll go check on some tutorials on that. I'm using MVC 5.2.3: <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />

Comment: @Janneman96 Definitely dig into authorizing with what .NET provides. You might have to customize a bit, but it works way better and you should generally not reinvent the wheel. I saw your update - does your `_BasicLayout.cshtml` contain a `<body>` tag?

Comment: @DionV. Yes it does, somehow i could not paste the first part of my code in here. Thanks for the tip, I'm following an [Authorize] tutorial now.

Comment: This is an example of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You asked about your proposed solution when you should have stated the reason for that solution in the first place. No, what you're doing is not a good idea. There's well established ways of dealing with authorization in MVC, one of them being [IAuthorizationFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iauthorizationfilter(v=vs.118).aspx) attributes such as the `[Authorize]` one mentioned above. Look into those!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use [Authorize]. I'm following this tutorial now:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF
Thanks to DionV.

Answer (score 0):

I've verified the code, and it seems to be functioning correctly on my machine.
[image]

also check the code

In View:

[image]

and in Layout (`_LayoutTest.cshtml` in my case)

[image]

But if we change the condition in `_LayoutTest.cshtml` Layout as:

```
 @if (0 != 1) // use if statements cautiously 
            {
                @RenderBody();
            }
```

The `@RenderBody()` method will work as:

[image]

Note: I'm currently working with ASP.NET Core MVC 6. Pardon me if my question is irrelevant to your project. Although the issue is closed, I wanted to experience the same problem you encountered.